# C# - Loading remote image and sending to browser using .ashx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to load a remote image from my Amazon S3 bucket and send it to browser in binary. I'm also trying to learn ASP.Net at the same time. I've been a classic programmer for many years and need to change. I started yesterday and have my first headache today.

On a page in my application I have this image element:

```
<img src="loadImage.ashx?p=rqrewrwr">
```

and on loadImage.ashx, I have this exact code:

```
-------------------------------------------------
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

string url = "https://............10000.JPG";
byte[] imageData;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
   imageData = client.DownloadData(url);
}

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
}
-------------------------------------------------
```

There is probably quite a lot wrong with this, as it's my first attempt at .net and don't know what I'm doing. To start with, I'm getting the following error but sure there's more to come.

```
CS0116: A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods
```

This is on line 3, which is `string url = "https://............"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an HttpHandler, you have to put the code in the code behind... if you expand loadimage.ashx in Solution Explorer, you should see a loadimage.ashx.cs file.  This file is where your logic should be, and all of it should be in the ProcessRequest method.

So loadimage.ashx should be basically empty:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="loadimage" %>
```

And loadimage.ashx.cs should contain the rest:

```
using System.Web;

public class loadimage : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string url = "https://............10000.JPG";
        byte[] imageData;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            imageData = client.DownloadData(url);
        }

        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create an aspx page that serves the image.  This removes the code behind requirement, but adds a little more overhead... create a loadimage.aspx page with the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<script language="c#" runat="server">
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "https://............10000.JPG";
        byte[] imageData;
        using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            imageData = client.DownloadData(url);
        }

        Response.ContentType = "image/png";  // Change the content type if necessary
        Response.OutputStream.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
</script>
```

Then reference this loadimage.aspx in the image src instead of the ashx.

Comment: I'm not using VS or Solution Explorer, I should have stated so. Am I able to just create a new file loadImage.ashx.cs in Dreamweaver for example?

Comment: I just created a new page loadImage.ashx.cs and got a new error: "Could not create type 'Handler'."

Comment: I'm not as familiar with Dreamweaver, but I believe you will have to create a class in a .cs file that handles the request.  The `Class` attribute declaration in the ashx file will have to point to the fully qualified class name (namespace and class name).

Comment: I've updated my response to include the a more complete code file.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I just updated my code to exactly what you have given me but got a similar error: "Could not create type 'loadImage'." on the ASHX file. I have nothing in my web.config file apart from URL rewrite rules, is that an issue?

Comment: There are multiple ways to register HTTP Handlers... when you use an ashx file, there are no additional requirements in the web.config.  It seems like the code file is just not getting compiled... does Dreamweaver precompile the code, or does it rely on IIS to compile at runtime?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14234/discussion-between-drumboog-and-paparazzokid)

Comment: This did actually help me for a moment, before I went over to PHP - sorry to waste your time. Even coming from Classic ASP for many years, it was taking a long to grasp how .Net worked, and I work on a mac so wasn't straight forward. I looked at PHP and I've nearly re-written my entire application since I spoke to you, it's so simple. Thanks again though :)