# Secret image path in WebForms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, .net-3.5

I am using Visual Studio 2008 (.NET framework 3.5) and currently I am uploading images to my ASP.NET WebForms application in C#. If some one copies my image url and opens in new window/tab then complete directory structure of my site is revealed to the user, some thing like `http://domain.name/images/companylogo/logo599.jpg`
I want to hide my directory structure and show image path something like:

http://www.zameen.com/common/resize.php?img=4/303088.jpg&d=&w=250&h=147&r=1
http://www.zameen.com/common/resize.php?img=7/165/bhurbun_continental_apartments_380.jpg&d=250&w=250&h=180&r=1
http://www.zameen.com/common/resize.php?img=2/156050.jpg&d=80&m=1

To hide my site directory structure I configured the imageshack API to upload images but requirements are like the path above. I am not getting how to manage the path format stated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found something that somehow meets my requirements. Check the link below, might be helpful to someone.
http://blog.kurtschindler.net/using-httphandlers-to-serve-image-files/

Answer (score 1):

You need to place you images in a folder not accessible by the user and serve the images via a handler. To make the folder inaccessible you can put a `web.config` file in that folder with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="DenyAll" path="*.*" verb="*" 
                 type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then add a `Generic Handler` (*.ashx) to your project andd do something like:

```
public class FileHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var path = GetPath(context.Request.Params["Id"]);
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.WriteFile(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response @chrfin. Actually users of my site are able to post images. Then what will be the result of your suggested configuration. I have no idea about handlers.

Comment: It doesn't matter "where" the images are from. If you put them in a folder with the `web.config` like in my example they can not be accessed directly and you need to get the `path` to server them somehow - like store them in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact implementation this is just an idea. Steps to get that.

1. Create a Table (database) or xml file to create a unique id and path for the image.
2. like ID=1 and path="~/folder/file.jpg".
3. Create a generic handler which will provide the image in response.
4. Use the image path like this if you have to call the image with code 1 "imagehandler?id=1"

Image Handler could be as below

```
 public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
 {
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var imageId = QueryString.getValueOf("ID");
        var imagePath="";//calculate for database or xml file
        var originalImage = Image.FromFile (context.Server.MapPath(imagePath);
        originalImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);  
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif"; //or any type
     }
  }
```

and give the image path to handler with image id.

Some useful links

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126421/Image-Handling-In-ASP-NET
2. http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

Comment: @shekhar can u provide me a demo link for detailed instructions? Things you talking about are new to me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create an .ashx handler that will serve requests to the images. Instead of calling

```
http://domain.name/images/companylogo/logo599.jpg
```

you could use

```
http://domain.name/photo.ashx?id=599
```

Example of the code: http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

If you use imageshack API or any other stuff to resize, etc. or images are located on remote server then you can code your handler as shown at [C# - Loading remote image and sending to browser using .ashx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597389/c-sharp-loading-remote-image-and-sending-to-browser-using-ashx-file)